Is there a way to direct Stanford CoreNLP to perform coreference resolution on a list of particular entities?
I have a list of entities identified via the CoreNLP NER module as part of an existing Java process we perform. I would like to run coreference resolution using those entities as input, rather than having the NER performed again. Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing this?
I have looked through the CoreNLP Java code but I can't find an obvious way of telling the coreference module to resolve references to a list of already identified entities.
